# Team Foundation Server Environments

Tags: asp.net, tfs

We are a small team of 3 developers.  We have a mix of classic ASP code and ASPX pages.  All the code is contained in one solution with multiple projects.  We are currently not using any VC software and have just install TFS 2013 and want to move to using its VC.  Our current environment is setup as follows.

- Development environment - new code or changes to existing code.
- Test Environment - once the code from development passes unit testing, it is moved here to allow users to test changes.
- Staging Environment - this is a mirror of production.  once the users have accepted the changes in test we migrate the code here to test and make sure it works against the mirror copy of the database(sql).
- Production Environment - code is not modified in this environment.

All of this is done manually and now that our staff has grown from 1 to 2 to 3 developers over the last 6 months we need to make use of version control. What we are not sure of is how to implement this same environment using TFSVC.  Do we need to install TFS in each environment and have the 4 separate copies of the code and then how do we migrate the code between each environment using TFS.  We need help and suggestions on how to set this up. We want to keep it simple since there is only 3 of us.

Comment: I would just add your dev code to source. I would assume that you would just promote your dev code to a test environment. Then once it passes there promote that to staging, and then to production. Though if an issue is found wouldn't it always fall back to dev to be fixed? Then once fixed go through the process again? Personally i would start out with Team Foundation Service, its free up to 5 users.

Comment: What I'm not sure of is how to structure it. should I have different folders for each environment and then how do you promote from one to the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you would have **one** TFS server that holds the sources for all of your environments. Many people implement a branching strategy to support different versions of source code deployed as part of different releases or in different staging environments.

Many people treat TFS as a Development Tool and as such it ends up in the development "network". We recommend people to treat TFS as a production server though, it contains your source code (Intellectual property and an large investment in knowledge and tme) and you might also use it to hold your Product Backlog (which could contain sensitive information on where your company wants to move in the future). If you were to lose any of them it would be a great loss. So make sure you treat the TFS server as something holding value and implement a proper backup & restore and disaster recovery procedure.

Helpful links:

- [ALM Rangers Planning Guide](http://vsarplanningguide.codeplex.com/)
- [ALM Rangers Version Control Guide (aka Branching Guide)](http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/)

Comment: +1 for the ALM guides.  Their branching advice for managing your dev/test/release code is really good.  That, and you might strongly consider using a cloud-based TFS service, instead of managing your own server -- then you have someone taking care of backups, updates, availability, etc.

Comment: Thank you to all that have commented.  I was just reading about branching and thought this might be the way I wanted to go to set this up. I will study the links you posted above and let you know if I have any other questions.  I'm still a little fuzzy on how to physically set this up but I'm sure it will become clearer once I read the guides above.